# I am getting few errors while running following simple react.js application .. any idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
var Button = React.createClass({
render: function  () {
 return:(
              <button>Go</button>
  )
}

});
React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My React Page</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    

</head>

<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/jsx" src="../1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting following errors in chrome console.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND react.js:113 Download
>   the React DevTools for a better development experience:
>   https://fb.me/react-devtools
>
> JSXTransformer.js:314 You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be
>   sure to precompile your JSX for production -
>   http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx
>
> JSXTransformer.js:215 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///D:/React.js/react-0.13.3/examples/MyApplication/1.js. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.load @
>   JSXTransformer.js:215
>
> JSXTransformer.js:215 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send'
>   on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file:///D:/React.js/react-0.13.3/examples/MyApplication/1.js'.

Comment: I guess the error is because you are trying to use in-browser jsx transformer. Try using loaders, which precompiles your jsx to js. you can try babel loader.

Comment: how to use babel loader?

Comment: My apologies. famousgarkin is correct. I had added babel loader in my solution and in webpack config, I had configure it for all *.jsx files

Answer (score 1):

This is not a React/JSX problem. You are running into the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) limitations of the Chrome web browser when loading the content directly off the filesystem.

Two ways you can go about this:

- Disable the Chrome CORS behavior with [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cors?hl=en&_category=extensions), or  maybe settings like `--disable-web-security` CLI flag and whatnot.
- Use a development web server like [node.js http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), [python SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), etc.

IMO the development web server option is more standard, portable, and transparent way to go about it than hacking around a specific web browser.

Then you also have an *Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 3: Unexpected token :*, so remove the erroneous `:` in the `Button.render` `return`.